# JVM How to analyze unreferenced objects?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, jprofiler

I have a Spring boot application, which consumes a lot of memory (1.1G) at startup. Through analyzing the heap dump, I found that about 1G of memory size is all unreferenced objects(mostly char[], int[], byte []). When I manually trigger a Full GC, the heap memory is reduced to 90MB. I tried to use `yourkit` to analyze where these unreferenced objects were created, but it didn't help.

How to determine where these unreferenced objects were created?

Comment: so even after you *analyse* these variables, what do you want to do about it?

Comment: I want to know how to determine where these unreferenced objects are created? 
 @ScaryWombat

Comment: Is that 1.1 GB actually a heap memory? How did you find that? If you want to record where do the allocations come from you can try 'Object allocation recording': https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/allocations.jsp

Comment: You will always have unreferenced objects in your application . Better you check why the garbage collection is not happening. Also you can use visual VM to get the heap dump and then using MAT you can check for any memory leakages. I have experienced heap size going down from 4 gb to 1gb just because I was using String.concat in a loop which I found using MAT.

Comment: The main reason for utilizing several GB of heap memory is that you have told the JVM that it is ok to use several GB of heap memory. Obviously, you’ve set the maximum heap  size as such, the memory is there and apparently not needed for other purposes, so why should the JVM waste CPU resources, to make unused memory…still unused but reported as “free”?